# Numerically guessing a polynomial rational function from its power series expansion

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, regression, numerical-calculus, pade-approximation

Suppose I have a function $f \in \mathbb{Q}(x, y)$ which does not have a pole at the origin (in particular I can write it as the ratio of two polynomials with integer coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[x, y]$ where the denominator does not vanish at the origin).

Suppose I know arbitrarily many exact terms of the Taylor expansion of $f$ at the origin, and I have a (relatively small) bound on the degree of both numerator and denominator.
What is the best way to guess $f$ from this data?

What I, as a pure mathematician who knows nothing about regressions and numerical methods, would try to do is to restrict to a sufficiently small neighborhood of zero (to stay away from poles), to approximate $f$ with its power series and then use some sort of rational polynomial regression to guess $f$.

The two problems I see with this is first that if I restrict myself to a too small neighborhood of $f$ it might look too flat and it would be impossible to interpolate and second that the series approximation is a rational function itself so my algorithm would probably guess that $f$ is just the input approximation or some truncation of it.
However, I hope to solve the second problem by using the hypothesis that I have a bound on the degrees of the polynomials in my fraction: if the neighborhood to which I restricted myself is not too small by adding enough terms I will get something that cannot be well approximated by a small degree polynomial but I will need to add a denominator.

So I have two more precise questions here: what would more experienced people try instead? If my idea is doable, what is a good way to make a regression on a multivariable polynomial rational function with integer coefficients?

Comment: You could move the expansion point and find the series expansion of $f$ away from $0$ by analytical continuation. I don't know if that is doable within the framework of your problem though?

Comment: Is there such a thing as a 2d Pade' approximation?

Comment: @Michaël no unfortunately the only numerical data I have is that of the function expansion at the origin

Comment: The coefficients of a rational function $f(x)$ obeys a linear recurrence. So, you can search for the recurrence to guess the formula for $f(x)$.  In two variables it's the same. Writing $f(x,y) = \sum_n a_n(y) x^n$, you can look for linear recurrences among the $a_n(y)$.